# How to do database routing in read-only and read-write with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm studying Transaction Routing in Spring, but my application has a runtime problem.

I have two MySQL databases, one for reading and one for reading/write, but my routing configuration is not working, when I apply the read-only configuration, I don't get success.

This is my configurations:

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>br.com.multidatasources</groupId>
    <artifactId>multidatasources</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>multidatasources</name>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
# Database master
master.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/billionaires?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
master.datasource.username=root
master.datasource.password=root

# Database slave
slave.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/billionaires?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
slave.datasource.username=root
slave.datasource.password=root

# Database driver
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# JPA property settings
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

**DataSourceType.java**

```
public enum DataSourceType {
    READ_ONLY,
    READ_WRITE
}
```

**TransactionRoutingDataSource.java**

```
public class TransactionRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly() ? DataSourceType.READ_ONLY : DataSourceType.READ_WRITE;
    }

}
```

**RoutingConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RoutingConfiguration {
    
    private final Environment environment;
    
    public RoutingConfiguration(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("routingDataSource") DataSource routingDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(routingDataSource);
        bean.setPackagesToScan(Billionaires.class.getPackageName());
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        bean.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return bean;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("routingDataSource") DataSource routingDataSource) {
        return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(routingDataSource);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource(
            @Qualifier("masterDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource,
            @Qualifier("slaveDataSource") DataSource slaveDataSource
    ) {
        TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new TransactionRoutingDataSource();
 
        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceType.READ_WRITE, masterDataSource);
        dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceType.READ_ONLY, slaveDataSource);
 
        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource());

        return routingDataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("master.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("master.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("master.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource slaveDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("slave.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("slave.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("slave.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
           
        return properties;
    }

}
```

**Billionaires.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "billionaires")
public class Billionaires {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    private String career;
    
    public Billionaires() { }

    public Billionaires(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String career) {        
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.career = career;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCareer() {
        return career;
    }

    public void setCareer(String career) {
        this.career = career;
    }
    
}
```

**BillionairesRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface BillionairesRepository extends JpaRepository<Billionaires, Long> {

}
```

**BillionairesService.java**

```
@Service
public class BillionairesService {
    
    private final BillionairesRepository billionairesRepository;

    public BillionairesService(BillionairesRepository billionairesRepository) {
        this.billionairesRepository = billionairesRepository;
    }
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)  // Should be used the READ_ONLY  (This point not working)
    public List<Billionaires> findAll() {
        return billionairesRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @Transactional // Should be used the READ_WRITE
    public Billionaires save(Billionaires billionaires) {
        return billionairesRepository.save(billionaires);
    }

}
```

In the BillionairesService class, I apply the `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` on `findAll` method for use the `READ_ONLY` data source, but this is not occurring.

The `findAll` method should be used the `READ_ONLY` data source and `save` method should be used the `READ_WRITE` data source.

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: When obtaining a connection from the datasource there doesn't have to be a transaction. As I suspect you are using open session in view (by default) this happens even before the datasource can determine the tx state.

Comment: Additional tip, you are using Spring Boot so you only need the datasource configuration, the JPA stuff can still be auto configured by Spring Boot as well as `@EnableTransactionManagement`. Also check if you are using the correct `TransactionSynchronizationManager` (there are 2 one reactive and one classic, you should use the latter one!).

Comment: @M.Deinum I use the `@EnableTransactionalManagement` to creating a bean `entityManagerFactory`, because without this setting causes the initializing exception:

`
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in br.com.multidatasources.multidatasources.service.BillionairesService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
`

Comment: The `TransactionSynchronizationManager` I'm using classic, nothing reactive.

Comment: `@EnableTransactionManagement` doesn't create that bean, it only registers the aspect to drive transactions. You should mark your `LazyDataSourceConnection` bean as `@Primary` so that it will be used by the auto configured entitymanager.

Comment: I removed `@EnableTransactionManagement` and mark my `LazyDataSourceConnection` as `@Primary` bean, but does not working, the application every using only `READ_WRITE` mode.

Comment: And as I stated in my first comment -> *"As I suspect you are using open session in view (by default) this happens even before the datasource can determine the tx state"*. So unless you turn that off, your connection will already be bound before the transaction has started.

Comment: certainly, how I do turn it off?

I have the property `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` configured in my `application.properties`, but it is not working.

Comment: That should disable it. Please update your config with your current state (as you only should have the datasource config, everything else should be automatic). Also how is that `findAll` called? If that is from an other `@Transactional` method it will not switch to a read only connection it will just participate in the current transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your help @M.Deinum, I solved this problem, I added the solution of this case to the answers of this post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to use autoconfiguration as-much as you can, it will make things a little simpler. The main key is to set to delay the getting of the connection and preparing it for the current transaction.

This can be achieved in 2 different ways.

1. Set the `prepareConnection` property of the `JpaDialect` to `false`. If you don't then the `JpaTransactionManager` will eagerly get `Connection` and prepare it for the transaction. This is even before it had time to set the current state of the transaction onto the `TransactionSynchronizationManager`. Which will make the call to `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly` always return `false` (as it is set at the end of the `doBegin` method in the `JpaTransactionManager`.
2. Set the `hibernate.connection.handling_mode` to `DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION`. This will delay the getting of a connection and close the connection after the transaction. Without Spring this is also the default for Hibernate 5.2+ (see the [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-connection-handling)) but for legacy reasons Spring switches this to `DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_HOLD`.

Either of these solutions will work as the preparing of the connection is delayed and the `JpaTransactionManager` has thus time to sync the state in the `TransactionSynchronizationManager`.

```java
@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor dialectProcessor() {

    return new BeanPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) {
                ((HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) bean).getJpaDialect().setPrepareConnection(false);
            }
            return bean;
        }
    };
}
```

However adding this property to your `application.properties` will also work:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION
```

With either one of these solutions you can now ditch your transaction configuration, jpa etc. There is also an easier way to configure multiple datasources. It is described in the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources) which will reuse as much of the Spring auto-configuration as possible.

First make sure the following is in your `application.properties`

```
# DATABASE MASTER PROPERTIES
master.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:masterdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
master.datasource.username=sa
master.datasource.password=sa
master.datasource.configuration.pool-name=Master-DB

# DATABASE SLAVE PROPERTIES
slave.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:slavedb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
slave.datasource.username=sa
slave.datasource.password=sa
slave.datasource.configuration.pool-name=Slave-DB

# JPA PROPERTIES SETTINGS
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

# ENABLE ERRORS IN DESERIALIZATION OF MISSING OR IGNORED PROPERTIES
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-ignored-properties=true

# ENABLE ERRORS ON REQUESTS FOR NON-EXISTENT RESOURCES
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true

# DISABLE MAPPINGS OF STATIC RESOURCES (IS NOT USABLE IN DEVELOPMENT OF APIs)
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
```

*NOTE:* Removed the driver for JDBC (not needed) only set `spring.jpa.database-platform` you set either `database` or `database-platform` not both.

Now with this and the following `@Configuration` class you will have 2 datasources, the routing one and the `BeanPostProcessor` as mentioned above (if you choose to use the property you can remove said `BeanPostProcessor`.

```java
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("master.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties masterDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("master.datasource.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource masterDataSource(DataSourceProperties masterDataSourceProperties) {
        return masterDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("slave.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties slaveDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("slave.datasource.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource slaveDataSource(DataSourceProperties slaveDataSourceProperties) {
        return slaveDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource(DataSource masterDataSource,  DataSource slaveDataSource) {
        TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new TransactionRoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceType.READ_WRITE, masterDataSource);
        dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceType.READ_ONLY, slaveDataSource);

        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource);

        return routingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor dialectProcessor() {

        return new BeanPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) {
                    ((HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) bean).getJpaDialect().setPrepareConnection(false);
                }
                return bean;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This will set up everything you need for this to work and still be able to use as much of the auto-configuration and detection as you can. With this, the only configuration you need to do is this `DataSource` setup. No JPA, Transaction management etc. as that will be done automatically.

Finally here is a test to test this with (you can test both scenarios). The read-only one will fail because there is no schema there, the save will succeed as there is a schema on the READ_WRITE side of things.

```java
@Test
void testDatabaseSwitch() {
    Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> billionaireService.findAll())
            .isInstanceOf(DataAccessException.class);

    Billionaire newBIllionaire = new Billionaire(null, "Marten", "Deinum", "Spring Nerd.");
    billionaireService.save(newBIllionaire);

}
```

Comment: This is a very good suggestion!

My fault was not having defined an `@Bean` as `@Primary`, for this reason, the `entityManager` initialization error occurred.

I am extremely grateful for having helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was wondering what setPrepareConnection was about because the docs were not clear to me.

Comment: Option 1 is working well for us but had to turn off auto-commit at the data source level (we missed the auto-commit configuration initially). So, auto-commit is also an important parameter for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing my implementation of the `RoutingConfiguration.java` class.

I configured the data source for using the `setAutoCommit(false)` configuration and added the property `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` with value `true`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RoutingConfiguration {

    private final Environment environment;

    public RoutingConfiguration(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("routingDataSource") DataSource routingDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName(getClass().getSimpleName());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(routingDataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(Billionaires.class.getPackageName());

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        HibernateJpaDialect jpaDialect = vendorAdapter.getJpaDialect();

        jpaDialect.setPrepareConnection(false);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager(entityManagerFactory));
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource(
            @Qualifier("masterDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource,
            @Qualifier("slaveDataSource") DataSource slaveDataSource
    ) {
        TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new TransactionRoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceType.READ_WRITE, masterDataSource);
        dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceType.READ_ONLY, slaveDataSource);

        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource());

        return routingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("master.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("master.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("master.datasource.password"));
        return connectionPoolDataSource(dataSource, determinePoolName(DataSourceType.READ_WRITE));
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource slaveDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("slave.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("slave.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("slave.datasource.password"));
        return connectionPoolDataSource(dataSource, determinePoolName(DataSourceType.READ_ONLY));
    }

    private HikariDataSource connectionPoolDataSource(DataSource dataSource, String poolName) {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig(dataSource, poolName));
    }

    private HikariConfig hikariConfig(DataSource dataSource, String poolName) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();

        hikariConfig.setPoolName(poolName);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 4);
        hikariConfig.setDataSource(dataSource);
        hikariConfig.setAutoCommit(false);

        return hikariConfig;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.database-platform"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit", "true");

        return properties;
    }

    private String determinePoolName(DataSourceType dataSourceType) {
        return dataSourceType.getPoolName().concat("-").concat(dataSourceType.name());
    }

}
```

The `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` allows the connection is acquired prior to calling the `determineCurrentLookupKey` method.

Comment: You can just set that property through `application.properties` you don't need to replace the auto configuration of JPA for that.

Comment: I tried to use this approach, but it doesn't have the desired effect, being necessary that I create the beans pertinent to the JPA settings myself.

Comment: This is the repository of the study case with the final solution: https://github.com/jonathanmdr/RoutingDataSource

Comment: You aren't setting the properties through JPA (as I mentioned you should) if you don't it ofcourse still won't work.

Comment: I did as per your directions, but it just didn't work.
For this reason, I kept the implementation as per the answer.