# Master-slave configuration on spring boot, @Transactional(readOnly = true) not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, master-slave

So I have a master-slave data source setup as follows :

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.myservice.notificationservice.repositories.happyoffer",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "happyofferEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "happyofferTransactionManager"
)
public class HappyofferDataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.entity.scan.packages}")
    private String packageToScan;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.happyoffer.datasource.master")
    public DataSourceProperties happyOfferMasterDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.happyoffer.datasource.master.configuration")
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        return happyOfferMasterDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.happyoffer.datasource.slave")
    public DataSourceProperties happyOfferSlaveDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "slaveDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.happyoffer.datasource.slave.configuration")
    public DataSource slaveDataSource() {
        return happyOfferSlaveDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource routingDataSource() {

        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        RoutingDataSourceConfiguration routingDataSourceConfiguration = new RoutingDataSourceConfiguration();
        DataSource master = this.masterDataSource();
        targetDataSources.put(DataSourceTypes.MASTER, master);
        DataSource slave = this.slaveDataSource();
        targetDataSources.put(DataSourceTypes.SLAVE, slave);
        routingDataSourceConfiguration.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        routingDataSourceConfiguration.setDefaultTargetDataSource(master);
        return routingDataSourceConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(routingDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = "happyofferEntityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean happyofferEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(routingDataSource())
                .packages(new String[]{packageToScan})
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager happyofferTransactionManager(final @Qualifier("happyofferEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean happyofferEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(happyofferEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "readerJdbcTemplate")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getReaderJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(slaveDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = "writerJdbcTemplate")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getWriterJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(masterDataSource());
    }
}
```

Routing configuration is defined as :

```
public class RoutingDataSourceConfiguration extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        boolean isReadOnly = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly();
        if(isReadOnly) {
            return DataSourceTypes.SLAVE;
        } else {
            return DataSourceTypes.MASTER;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a repository class defined as :

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface DeviceInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<DeviceInfo,Integer> {

    List<DeviceInfo> findAllByUserIdIn(List<Integer> userIds);
}
```

I'm simply calling the above function in a service like this :

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class NotificationShooterServiceImpl implements NotificationShooterService {

    @Autowired
    DeviceInfoRepository deviceInfoRepository;

    @Override
    public NotificationShooterResponse shoot(List<Integer> userIds) throws Exception {
       

        List<DeviceInfo> deviceInfoList = deviceInfoRepository.findAllByUserIdIn(userIds);
        log.info("Size : " + deviceInfoList.size());
        ..........
        ..........
        ..........
        NotificationShooterResponse notificationShooterResponse = new NotificationShooterResponse();
        notificationShooterResponse.setCountOfUniqueUserIds(deviceInfoList.size());

        return notificationShooterResponse;
    }
```

Now, as I have added `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`, I expect that the query will get routed to SLAVE db. However, I'm seeing it going to MASTER each time.
I debugged this and found that the readOnly attribute is not set to true for this transaction i.e.
in the file `RoutingDataSourceConfiguration` shown above,
`boolean isReadOnly = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly();` reads `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In short the solution for this problem is adding `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true` to `application.properties` and in case Hikari is used also setting `setAutoCommit(false)`.

[More details can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68078228/5494979)